# Gmail not allowing to login only with personal gmail account if one of my accounts is managed by organisation

Tags: google-chrome, safari, gmail, okta, google-account

I have a gmail account managed by my organisation. But I want to only login my personal gmail account in my browser.
I tried logging into gmail when no account is logged in, gmail redirects to the organisational login page(managed by okta).
I tried logging in with both gmail accounts and then signing out of organisation's gmail account but its logout is only possible if I logout of all my gmail accounts.
I tried this in multiple browsers (Google Chrome and Safari) but facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to use a Private Browsing Window. There are session settings with your organisation's account that conflict with what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to keep my personal gmail logged in, instead of logging in everytime.